# R returning table() from a custom function

Tags: r, function

I am trying to run EDA in **R** using `table()` for 100+ variables.

When I run the codes below, they are working correctly.

```
  var_freq <- table(dataset$count)
  var_freq_df <- as.data.frame(var_freq)
  var_freq_df$percent <-var_freq_df$Freq/ sum(var_freq_df$Freq)


> var_freq_df
   V1     N      percent
1:  0 68432 4.487138e-01
2:  1 80979 5.309855e-01
3:  2  2383 1.562551e-02
4:  3   654 4.288328e-03
5:  4    49 3.212967e-04
6:  5     8 5.245661e-05
```

Since I have 100+ variables, I wrote the custom function below.

```
  categ_EDA <- function(dataset,var){
 var_freq <- NULL
  var_freq <- table(dataset$var)
  var_freq_df <- as.data.frame(var_freq)
  var_freq_df$percent <-var_freq_df$Freq/ sum(var_freq_df$Freq)

  return( var_freq_df)
}
 categ_EDA(dataset,count)
```

which return this result.

```
  >  categ_EDA(dataset,count)
[1] Freq    percent
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I also used data.table instead of as.data.frame, which has a different error.

The part that puzzled me the most is that those codes work fine outside of a function, but didn't work within a custom function. Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: Most likely the problem is your use of "$". Try using "[[" instead. But also ... there's no looping construct that would be expected to "roll" over your variables in a dataset. Which brings up the question: Why not use `summary`?

Comment: Hi 42, Thanks a lot for your quick response! You are so right that removing $ and using [,] worked. Summary is a great idea. I am going to use summary for many variables and use the custom function for some vars. Thanks again. I appreciate your help!